# How can I install apps from unknown sources using my Google account on the web?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, sync, unknown-sources

I was wondering whether or not I can somehow remotely install applications from "unknown sources" i.e not having to copy the .apk file onto my device and then installing.

For example, using the Google Playstore on the web, I can manage all my apps using a browser on my laptop or pc. However those are in-store apps. How would I go about installing out-side the store apps remotely on my device using Google account (if that's even possible), or perhaps any other way without having to physically connect my device or having the .apk on my device.

**Note**
*Since it obviously isn't possible to do it from the playstore using a browser as it only allows playstore apps to be installed, any app would do. *

Comment: If the device is rooted then you may host an SSH server (I use this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimatepro)) on your Android and can access root shell from anywhere. The said app can copy a file to your device which you can install by using `pm install filename.apk` with root privileges. The issue that would arise is to know the IP address of your device every time the ISP changes it. That can be solved using some dynamic DNS updater app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your device is rooted, you can create **Install Job** in [SureMDM](https://suremdm.42gears.com).

Step 1: Create an free account [here](http://www.42gears.com/products/suremdm/).
Step 2: Install Mobile agent [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nix&hl=en).
Step 3: Login to Web admin console [here](https://suremdm.42gears.com/default.aspx).
Step 4: Click on Jobs on Utility panel.
Step 5: New Job > Android > Install program > Job name > Local File path.
Step 6: Apply the job.
Step 7: You can verify the status of Install Job in the System Log.
[It works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJJIk.png)

Answer (score -2):

The way the Google Play Store works is that they simply tell the device to download the app from the playstore. The device then initiates the download directly from the play store.

It is difficult to replicate this, so instead what applications tend to do is send the apk itself rather than just a link to the apk. [AirDroid](https://www.airdroid.com/) is one application that lets you install apps from your desktop computer directly to your remotely connected phone.

Comment: AFAIK, Airdroid should be launched and running before you can access the device remotely. But if the device is at some remote location, then how can I launch it first, then see what IP address is available, let alone accessing my device for any purpose. Please mention a use-case scenario for the purpose of this question. Airdroid isn't specific to the question only so I think a scenario is definitely required here. It would be really helpful if screenshots can be provided.