# Method for installing apps on corporate devices to be deployed to users

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, accounts

I'm trying to figure out what the best method is to pre-install and setup the airwatch agent on devices that are going to be deployed.

Currently, we log into Play store with our generic account and install airwacth agent, set up the phone for the user, then remove our generic gmail account.

This process causes issues though because when the user later logs in with their own gmail account, the app we installed under our own account doesn't auto update. It does allow the app to be updated if they manually navigate to it in the store but even doing this doesn't seem to add the app to their auto update list (I had thought that maybe doing one manual update would effectively cause their account take ownership of that app but it doesn't seem to be the case).

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/q/110218/119358

Comment: It's a little different. I have physical access to the device and am able to install the mdm app. The problem is that after I install it and remove our gmail account (that was used to log into the store and install the mdm app) the mdm app falls into limbo because the user will eventually log in with their own gmail account and the previously installed apps wont update.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. I don't want to sound stupid, but have you selected the auto-update setting to be turned on for the app on the play store? You can turn on auto-update in the settings of google play store app and then navigate to the app and press the menu button and tick the auto update button.

**Or**

2. Delete [Airwatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airwatch.androidagent&hl=en) and ask the users to download the app again.
   They can then recive auto-updates as the app is linked to their
   account

**Idea:** From what I know you can deploy apps via Airwatch, so try deploying the Airwatch app update to the phones. *(This is only an idea, It probably wont work, but is worth a try*

Comment: We already have an MDM (airwatch).

Comment: What I'm wondering is how to update the main MDM client when it was installed on the phone under one account, but the user later logs in under a different account (original account used to install MDM has since been removed).

Comment: @GeorgeKendros I Don't want to sound stupid, but have you selected the auto-update setting to be turned on for the app on the play store? You can turn on auto-update in the settings of google play store app and then navigate to the app and press the menu button and tick the auto update button. IF this worked for you I will change my answer to reflect this.